# Google cloud sql cannot assign an access IP

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am attempting to setup a rails 3.2 app on Google compute engine,  not app engine.  I want to use Google cloud sql.  When reading the docs I know I need to assign access ips,  however the ability to do that is no where to be found. I can allow app engine applications, but not an ip.

The edit menu in the console doesn't seem to have what I need even though the docs point me there.

Has anyone done this? Where and how do you assign an ip to your Google cloud sql instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project
2. Choose your project and click it's name
3. Click cloud SQL on the left side menu
4. Choose the instance ID you wish to assign an ip to and click it's name
5. Click edit
6. Scroll down past 'Resources and Billing'. Just below 'Options' is an 'Assign IP Address' section